# Can't instantiate a class inside another PHP

Tags: php

How can I instatiate athe class `OM` inside the `MySQL_DataMapper`?

Here is the MySQL_DataMapper.php:

```
<?php
namespace asc {

    include('../../models/OM.php');

    class MySQL_DataMapper
    {
        [omitted code for simplicity]

        public function fetchAllOMs()
        {
            $query = "REALLY LONG QUERY";
            $result = $this->pdo->query($query);
            $OMs = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch()){
                $OM = new OM($row['id_organizacao_militar'], $row['nome'], $row['sigla'], $row['forca_armada']);
                array_push($OMs, );
            }
            var_dump($OMs);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the error I get:

```
Warning: include(../../models/OM.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/alekrabbe/PhpstormProjects/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php on line 10

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../models/OM.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/alekrabbe/PhpstormProjects/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'asc\OM' not found in /home/alekrabbe/PhpstormProjects/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php:37 Stack trace: #0 /home/alekrabbe/PhpstormProjects/stm_asc/views/cadastro-militar.php(13): asc\MySQL_DataMapper->fetchAllOMs() #1 {main} thrown in /home/alekrabbe/PhpstormProjects/stm_asc/controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php on line 37
```

I don't understand why it fails as I did just that on another php file and it worked there. Thank you.

### EDIT 1

Forgot to mention but the class OM.php is also in the asc namespace.

Here it is:

```
<?php
namespace asc{
    class OM
    {
        private $id;
        private $nome;
        private $sigla;
        private $forca_armada;

        public function __construct($id, $nome, $sigla, $forca_armada)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->nome = $nome;
            $this->sigla = $sigla;
            $this->forca_armada = $forca_armada;
        }

        [Gets and Sets]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `include __DIR__ . "/../../models/OM.php";` and make sure the path is correct

EDIT: the better way is to use an autoloader as @Alex Howansky mentioned in a comment on his answer, but in a pinch just make sure the path is correct and use **DIR**.

Answer (score 3):

You're inside a namespace:

```
namespace asc {
```

So references to `OM` become `asc\OM`. Fix this by anchoring to the root namespace:

```
$OM = new \OM(...);
```

Comment: Even it the class OM is in the same namespace? I forgot to add that to the question. Just edited the question with the OM class.

Comment: `include(../../models/OM.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just use an autoloader and PSR-4 naming and your problems will go away. Modern PHP code should (pretty much) never use `include` or `require`.

Comment: I tried using an autoloader when I first ran into thia problem, but for some other reason it also did not recognize my project files. Maybe I should give it another try.